# WPF - C# DialogResult.OK in a window

Tags: c#, wpf, savefiledialog

I hava a wpf application when I am using a page the DialogResult.OK works fine but I just notice that  when  I am in a window it doesn't allow this property

as the code  bellow

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class preDownloadXml : Window 
{

    private void CallTheDialog(){
       SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = SaveFileDialog();
          if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
             // to do
          }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way  to  get  the Dialog Result in a Window ?

Comment: Winforms and WPF both have a DialogResult, they are not the same type.  You have to spell the full name.  Or consider using the WPF flavor of this dialog, it is in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace.

Comment: oh, it's good to know that  I will  try it

Comment: Check the return type of `saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()`, does it return a `DialogResult`?

Comment: thank  you  both, @HansPassant was exactly  where I was  mistaking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution as  @HansPassant mentioned was that
Windowsform and WPF both hava a DialogResult and they are not the same  type

so that's my final code

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class preDownloadXml : Window 
{

    private void CallTheDialog(){
       Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
       bool? result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()
          if(result == true){
             // to do
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you don't need that using directive anymore.  Your code is now pure WPF.

Comment: there are more code than this one in my cs file, I just simplified it to post here